# Is there a repo where you can download android virtual devices?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Does anyone know, if vendors provide or if there is a site where one could download AVD profiles for existing android devices on the market so you can run your apps in the emulator and basically see how they will run on said devices?

I know it's pretty easy to create a new device but it'd be great if one could just download the config file for each device and run it.

Comment: It is seriously disappointing that Google does not provide some leadership in this area. They could update the terms of using the free Android OS to require device makers to publish AVD profiles to make it a bit easier for developers. And it would be great if the tools for Eclipse could automatically fetch and display them as options.

Answer (score 46):

I just created a repo to store sample AVD images.  Basically you can clone this Git repo into your local .android folder, to get these basic emulator images pre-configured.

https://github.com/mwolfson/AndroidAVDRepo

I plan to add more emulator images, but have a fairly representative set of devices emulated now.  Pull requests are welcome.

Comment: This fork has more comprehensive list: [https://github.com/j5at/AndroidAVDRepo](https://github.com/j5at/AndroidAVDRepo)

Comment: I didn't even know about this fork - to be honest, I totally abandoned the original project.  This makes me so happy to see that this lives on (in better form).  Open Source rules.

Comment: I cannot get the j5at fork to work on Mac w/ Android Studio 3.0.1.  As the devs have disabled the Issues feature, I find this repo completely unusable.

Comment: It seems that mwolfson's repo has been updated and is now fresher than j5at's.

Comment: It was outdated 5 years ago.

Answer (score 12):

I found [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/) page which helped a lot.

Comment: Except it's for the older version.  I'll try to find one for latest 21.1 Version.

Comment: I wonder why this 10-year-old stuff is still here. Completely obsolete.

Answer (score 11):

I found this page which looks quite comprenhensive from Samsung devices:
http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Samsung-Emulators-for-Android-Application-Development

I agree with Brennan that Google should make the it compulsory for each device.

It seems that they should work for Android Studio as well see [How to reuse the existing AVDs for android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608530/how-to-reuse-the-existing-avds-for-android-studio)

Comment: These are just skins

Comment: And the download link doesn't work anymore.