# How to reuse the existing AVDs for android-studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was using Eclipse as my android development IDE.

I just have installed the android-studio. I want to reuse the AVDs in Android-studio which i was using previously with the eclipse. How can I import those AVDs in the Android-studio,
Is it possible , or should I download the new AVDs using the android-studio's AVD Manager

My Eclipse path

```
d:\my_work\Android\Eclipse\
```

and my Android SDK path

```
d:\my_work\Android\Android-sdk\
```

but my Android-Studio path is

```
c:\program files(x86)\Android\Android-studio
```

**Update**

Here is my Avd Directory
[image]

I have created 2 AVDs as you can see the folder `Android_2.3.3.avd` and `AVD_for_10_1in_WXGA_Tablet.avd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most regular installs of the SDK/etc make a /.android folder in your USER folder (for Windows, atleast).

In this folder you will find a avd folder. this holds all of the AVDs you have.

Generating a new AVD in Android Studio put an avd profile in the same folder as generating one from the base SDK/Eclipse did for me ($USER/.android/avd), which makes sense due the AVD being sort of a separate entity (although Android Studio comes with its own SDK).

I hope this information helps you with your configuration.

EDIT: I did some digging through the Android Studio source and found this..

```
   * Returns the value for property lastSdkPath as stored in the properties file
   * at $HOME/.android/ddms.cfg, or null if the file or property doesn't exist.
   *
   * This is only useful in a scenario where existing users of ADT/Eclipse get Diamond,
   * but without the bundle. This method duplicates some functionality of
   * {@link com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation} since we don't want any file system
   * writes to happen during this process.
   */
```

My guess is that since I had eclipse already installed with the Android SDK, it used my files I already setup.

In your case, you probably didn't have this happen (even though it should, since you used eclipse). I'm going to continue looking for the source for some sort of "default" sdk/avd install to see if I can directly help you, but you basically need to search for a .avd folder somewhere on your harddrive.

Comment: so basically what you are saying is that I have to make other avds for Eclipse and Android studio separately?

Comment: Please check out my edit. Are you sure your avd's from eclipse are not showing in Android studio?

Comment: Also, try changing the enviroment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME to wherever your .android folder is located (so if you find it located in C:\, set ANDROID_SDK_HOME to C:\)

If this does not work, can you tell me where your AVDs are located at in Eclipse?

Comment: What is your ANDROID_SDK_HOME set to?

Comment: Did you just manually set this? or was it set to this before? 

Note this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841766/possible-to-change-where-android-virtual-devices-are-saved

according to that, you might have to change your sdk home to D:\my_work, or D:\my_work\Android